# Set data from returned (201) JSON Object into Local Storage using AngularJS (angular-local-storage)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, local-storage

New at dealing with Local Storage and Angular.

Here is the code in my factory when posting a new user...

```
    function postRegistration(registration) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: localApi + '/users',
            dataType: "json",
            data: registration,
            headers: {
                'content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).then(function (info){
            return info;
        }, function (error) {
            return error;
        })

     }
```

I am looking to take more specifically just the UserId that is returned when the data has a 201 status, and set it directly into my local storage using a package "angular-local-storage" that has been injected into my html and app module.

I understand how to set up the local storage, I simply can't figure out how to take my returned data, and set into local storage so I can access the UserId later...

Watched many tutorials, and read several articles can not find something specific to my needs.

Thank you in advance for your help!